# Phaser game.states not loading

Tags: javascript, phaser-framework

This is one of my JavaScript files. All my other files work, except for this one. When I run stacks, it gives me a reference error that my over.js file is not defined.

I've loaded several other pages. I don't know why just this one is not loading.

This is my over.js file:

```
var over = {

  preload: function() {
    game.load.spritesheet('button', 'assets/button.png', 215, 53, 8);
  },

  create: function() {
    this.btnplayAgain = game.add.button(110, 400, 'button', this.playAgain, this, 2, 3, 2);
  },

  playAgain: function() {
    game.state.start("main");
  },

  update: function() {},
};
```

And my main.js the ending of my code is this:

```
var game = new Phaser.Game(480, 640, Phaser.AUTO);
game.state.add('over', over); //<----------------This one doesn't work

game.state.add('main', MainState);
game.state.add('stateTitle', stateTitle);
game.state.start('stateTitle');
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: When you have an error that you would like to debug, please copy base the exact error message into your question; it's very hard to help you otherwise. Thanks!

Comment: Minor content and styling edits to improve quality of question.

Comment: Can you show us the html where you load the various .js files?  My first guess is that you ended up not loading the `over.js` file for some reason.

Comment: main.js:191 Uncaught ReferenceError: stateOver is not defined(…)(anonymous function) @ main.js:191

Comment: <head>
 <title></title>
 <meta charset="utf-8">
 <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, minimum-scale=1, user-scalable=no">
 <script type="text/javascript" src="js/phaser.js"></script>
 <script src="js/stateTitle.js"></script>
 <script src="js/main.js"></script>
 <script src="js/stateOver.js"></script>
  <style>
  body {
   padding: 0px;
   margin: 0px;
   background: black;
  }

 </style>
</head>

Comment: Its stateOver.js the one im loading now I switched the name

Comment: Also I did notice My game does work if at the end in the game.state.start("StateOver", StateOver); IF I remove the second part after the coma StateOver like this game.state.start("StateOver"); my game runs but its not connecting my main.js to my stateOver.js

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When using states with Phaser make sure you load the javascript files for the states before you load the javascript file for your main state. Edit your HTML file as such

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/phaser.js"></script> 
<script src="js/stateTitle.js"></script> 
<script src="js/stateOver.js"></script>
<script src="js/main.js"></script>
```

This would remove the error that you are encountering. The main reason for the error is that the `main.js` file gets loaded first and it checks for the state `over`. Since the file that contains the state `over` has not been loaded yet, so it throws an exception that the state is not defined.

Comment: I was just about to write that i figured it out I did exactly that and now my game works!!!

Answer (score 0):

Simply by rearranging my load scripts my problem got fixed my main.js was in-front of my over.js which made it not work.